# MySQL fulltext in boolean mode doesn't match word (not disqualified word)

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

MySQL fulltext search doesn't match the word 'christoffer82' and its ilk with the root word 'christo' and I have no idea why. This login only appears once in the table (it doesn't appear in more than 50% of the results) and it is not even an excluded word.

NOK

```
SELECT
    usr.ID_USER AS userId
    , usr.USER_LOGIN AS userLogin
    , usr.EMAIL AS email
    , usr.MOBILE_PHONE AS mobilePhone
    , usr.FIRSTNAME AS firstName
    , usr.SURNAME AS surname
    , usr.USER_CREATED AS userCreated
    , usr.DATE_CREATED AS dateCreated
    , usr.USER_MODIFIED AS userModified
    , usr.DATE_MODIFIED AS dateModified
FROM
    BDT_USERS_DUMMY usr
WHERE 
    MATCH (usr.USER_LOGIN) AGAINST ('+christoffer82' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

OK

```
SELECT
    usr.ID_USER AS userId
    , usr.USER_LOGIN AS userLogin
    , usr.EMAIL AS email
    , usr.MOBILE_PHONE AS mobilePhone
    , usr.FIRSTNAME AS firstName
    , usr.SURNAME AS surname
    , usr.USER_CREATED AS userCreated
    , usr.DATE_CREATED AS dateCreated
    , usr.USER_MODIFIED AS userModified
    , usr.DATE_MODIFIED AS dateModified
FROM
    BDT_USERS_DUMMY usr
WHERE 
    MATCH (usr.USER_LOGIN) AGAINST ('+johan84' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I tried everything I could find on stackOverflow

Comment: can you provide a fiddle, which also shows which version you are using

Comment: I have veriosn 8.0.27

Comment: this seems to work just fine https://dbfiddle.uk/8n2azME7  so wjat exactly is your problem not ok is a bad description, but maybe you can update your version and all will be fixed

Comment: Why do you use fulltext search on a field that seems to contain only one word?

Comment: Sorry guys I have problem with my local server when I tried it on my online hosting then select to database works as I expected. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Problem was realy on my server and fulltext works :)

my.ini

```
increase => innodb_ft_max_token_size=50
add => innodb_ft_num_word_optimize=5000
add => innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree=10
```

and rebuild index

Comment: What `CHARACTER SET` is that column?  Probably `utf8mb4`.  I see that `christoffer82` is 13 _characters_ and note that 13*4 > 50.  I wonder if this explains it.  (The other two settings seem to affect performance.)

Answer (score 0):

```
AGAINST ('+christo*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

It may pick up something you did not want, but I am pretty sure it will match `christoffer82`.